# Whitespace-important parsing with Parse::RecDescent (eg. HAML, Python)

Tags: perl, parsing, grammar, parse-recdescent

I'm trying to parse HAML ([haml.info](http://haml.info)) with [Parse::RecDescent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::RecDescent). If you don't know haml, the problem in question is the same as parsing Python - blocks of syntax are grouped by the indentation level.

Starting with a very simple subset, I've tried a few approaches but I think I don't quite understand either the greediness or recursive order of P::RD. Given the haml:

```
%p
  %span foo
```

The simplest grammar I have that I think should work is (with bits unnecessary for the above snippet):

```
<autotree>

startrule           : <skip:''> block(s?)
non_space           : /[^ ]/
space               : ' '
indent              : space(s?)
indented_line       : indent line
indented_lines      : indented_line(s) <reject: do { Perl6::Junction::any(map { $_->level } @{$item[1]}) != $item[1][0]->level }>
block               : indented_line block <reject: do { $item[2]->level <= $item[1]->level }>
                    | indented_lines
line                : single_line | multiple_lines
single_line         : line_head space line_body newline | line_head space(s?) newline | plain_text newline

# ALL subsequent lines ending in | are consumed
multiple_lines      : line_head space line_body continuation_marker newline continuation_line(s)
continuation_marker : space(s) '|' space(s?)
continuation_line   : space(s?) line_body continuation_marker

newline      : "\n"
line_head    : haml_comment | html_element
haml_comment : '-#'
html_element : '%' tag

# TODO: xhtml tags technically allow unicode
tag_start_char : /[:_a-z]/i
tag_char       : /[-:_a-z.0-9]/i
tag            : tag_start_char tag_char(s?)

line_body    : /.*/
plain_text   : backslash ('%' | '!' | '.' | '#' | '-' | '/' | '=' | '&' | ':' | '~') /.*/ | /.*/
backslash    : '\\'
```

The problem is in the `block` definition. As above, it does not capture any of the text, though it does capture the following correctly:

```
-# haml comment
%p a paragraph
```

If I remove the second `reject` line from the above (the one on the first `block` rule) then it does capture everything, but of course incorrectly grouped since the first block will slurp all lines, irrespective of indentation.

I've also tried using lookahead actions to inspect `$text` and a few other approaches with no luck.

Can anyone (a) explain why the above doesn't work and/or (b) if there's an approach without using perl actions/rejects? I tried grabbing the number of spaces in the indent, and then using that in an interpolated lookahead condition for the number of spaces in the next line, but I could never quite get the interpolation syntax right (since it requires an arrow operator).

Answer (score 0):

Far better off doing some of the work outside of PRD.

```
my @stack = [ -1, [{}] ];
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   s/^( *)//;
   my $indent = length($1);

   if ($indent < $stack[-1][0]) {
      pop @stack while $indent < $stack[-1][0];
      die "Indent mismatch\n" if $indent != $stack[-1][0];
   }
   elsif ($indent > $stack[-1][0]) {
      my $children = $stack[-1][1][-1]{children} = [];
      push @stack, [ $indent, $children ];
   }

   push @{ $stack[-1][1] }, $parser->parse_line($_);
}

die "Empty document\n" if !$stack[0][1][0]{children};
die "Multiple roots\n" if @{ $stack[0][1][0]{children} } > 1;

my $root = $stack[0][1][0]{children}[0];
```

`$parser->parse_line($_)` is expected to return a hash ref.